# Toggle button does not appear

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make toggle button for my navigation menu, using [this](https://github.com/LearnWebCode/declarativeToggle).
Here is the js loaders

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/cycle2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/declarativeToggle.js"></script>
```

Here is the menu button and the navigation menu:

```
<span data-toggle-target=".site-nav" class="toggle-btn">MENU</span>
<nav class="site-nav">
    <ul class="group">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="hide-small"><a href="#">About us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FAQs</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Links</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>   
    </ul>
</nav>
```

And here is the css to make the show and hide:

```css
.toggle-btn {display: none;}
.toggle-btn-visible {display: block;}
.toggle-target-hidden {display: none;}
.toggle-target-expanded {display: block;}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .toggle-btn-visible {display: block;}
    .toggle-target-hidden {display: none;}
    .toggle-target-expanded {display: block;}
}
```

The problem is when i load the page the `MENU` button does not appear, and it is because of `.toggle-btn {display: none;}`

Also when i remove this it does not work(hide / show).

What is wrong here?

Comment: Did you make sure the two local js files where loaded in the page ?

Comment: yes they are loaded correctly

Comment: Try and use an id instead of a class : `data-toggle-target="#site-nav"` and `<nav id="site-nav">`

Comment: Nothing is wrong, the toggle button should be visible on display less then 768px wide - it should get class `toggle-btn-visible`.

Answer (score -1):

You must set **.toggle-btn {display: block;}** in  **@media screen and (max-width: 767px)**

your css must be

```
.toggle-btn {display: none;}
.toggle-btn-visible {display: block;}
.toggle-target-hidden {display: none;}
.toggle-target-expanded {display: block;}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
.toggle-btn {display: block;}
.toggle-btn-visible {display: block;}
.toggle-target-hidden {display: none;}
.toggle-target-expanded {display: block;}
}
```

Comment: please take a look at tutorial.

Comment: can you check from console. does javascript add **toggle-btn-visible** class to  toogle-btn?